# how to make a jar with Maven in Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I tried making and it gives an error when i opened it.
I'm using javafx.
I use many online dependences.
I first tried by going maven>lifecycle>install, after doing this when i tried to run the jar, it says that there's no manifest even though it's there.
I also tried through the artifacts but it also gives error.
P.S. I ran the jar on the CMD with java -jar "file's name".jar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: my own MANIFEST.MF file doesn't take effect in a maven built jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367542/java-my-own-manifest-mf-file-doesnt-take-effect-in-a-maven-built-jar)

Comment: Please show your pom file otherwise it's impossible to help...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.